Minimum Number of Base Accelerations Needed to Simulate Gaussian White Noise in Structural Dynamics?
I am currently working on a scientific paper where I subject a structure to base accelerations modeled as Gaussian white noise. I am relatively new to signal processing and would appreciate some guidance on my approach.
Here is a brief description of my MATLAB code:
Nrb = 20;  % Number of random white noise signals
Tmaxs = 30;  % Maximum time, in seconds
Fs = 100;  % Sampling frequency, in Hz

% Pre-allocation of variables
acc = cell(1, Nrb);

for j4 = 1:Nrb
    acc{j4} = randn(Tmaxs*Fs, 1);  % Generate each random white noise signal
end

In this code, I generate 20 random signals, each with a duration of 30 seconds and a sampling frequency of 100 Hz. My goal is to simulate base accelerations as Gaussian white noise and use them in my structural dynamics analysis.
Regarding the properties of the structure I'm analyzing, it has natural periods up to 5 seconds. Therefore, considering the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem, I chose a sampling frequency Fs = 100 Hz. This ensures that I can accurately capture the dynamics of my system, as it is well above twice the highest frequency of interest (0.2 Hz, corresponding to the 5-second period).
Due to computational constraints, I cannot use a very large number of signals.
My questions are:

What is the minimum number of base acceleration signals needed to approximate a Gaussian white noise process accurately?
Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind when generating and using these signals for structural dynamics analysis?

I have also attached a figure showing one of the white noise-like signals and the power spectral density of all 20 accelerations generated by the code. I used Welch's method to estimate the PSD

Thank you for your help!

Is the white noise an excitation signal for system identification?

@Stephen, this study uses Gaussian white noise to model random base accelerations for structural analysis, simulating seismic events at bedrock level, rather than for traditional system identification.

Regarding your second question, as seen in your plots, one of the problems is that Matlab's randn function will not produce a random Gaussian signal that has uniform spectral density (that is, white noise). Neither, for that matter, will Matlab's idinput function (which just filters randn to approximately achieve the desired bandwidth). As such, if you use the output of either, then you won't provide a uniform excitation source for all frequencies.
To obtain random Gaussian white noise, an approach I developed that works quite well is to use randn as an initial guess, then simply normalise amplitudes in the frequency domain. This achieves the ideal white noise circular autocorrelation impulse function.
Here is example Matlab code for doing so, which I've developed in a way such that you can specify your desired mean and variance, and, if you want to restrict the bandwidth, you can, but unlike Matlab's idinput function, I've done it as an ideal band pass filter to achieve it exactly:
Fs = 100;               % sample rate (hz)
TMaxs = 30;             % maximum time (s)
band = [0, Fs/2];       % noise bandwidth (hz) [lower limit, upper limit]
target_mean = 0;        % note: if bandwidth lower limit isn't 0 hz, then won't be set
target_variance = 1;

n = round(Fs*TMaxs);

% use randn to provide the intial guess
time = (0:n-1)/Fs;
noise_initial_guess = randn(n,1);

% compute intial guess fft
freq = (0:n-1)/n*Fs;
fft_noise_initial_guess = fft(noise_initial_guess);

% normalise amplitudes
fft_noise_final = ones(size(fft_noise_initial_guess)).*exp(1i*angle(fft_noise_initial_guess));

% let's limit the bandwidth
tmp = freq;
tmp(tmp > Fs/2) = Fs - tmp(tmp > Fs/2);
fft_noise_final(tmp < band(1) | tmp > band(2)) = 0;

% set target mean and variance
if band(1) ~= 0
    % if the bandwidth doesn't include 0 hz, then the mean must be zero
    fft_noise_final(1) = target_mean*n;
end
fft_noise_final(2:end) = fft_noise_final(2:end)*sqrt(target_variance/sum(abs(fft_noise_final(2:end)).^2))*n;

% perform inverse fft to obtain final random Gaussian white noise signal
noise_final = ifft(fft_noise_final,[],1,'symmetric');

% display results
subplot(2,3,1); plot(freq, abs([fft_noise_initial_guess, fft_noise_final])/n,'.-');
title('frequency domain'); xlabel('frequency (hz)'); ylabel('amplitude')
subplot(2,3,4); plot(time, [noise_initial_guess, noise_final],'.-');
title('time domain'); xlabel('time (s)'); ylabel('amplitude')

% check gaussian shape
subplot(2,3,2); histogram(noise_initial_guess);
title('initial guess distribution');
subplot(2,3,5); histogram(noise_final)
title('final distribution');

% check autocorrelation
circ_auto_initial_guess = ifft(fft_noise_initial_guess.*conj(fft_noise_initial_guess), 'symmetric');
circ_auto_final = ifft(fft_noise_final.*conj(fft_noise_final), 'symmetric');
subplot(2,3,3); plot(time, [circ_auto_initial_guess, circ_auto_final])
legend({'initial guess','final'})
grid on; title('circular autocorrelation'); xlabel('time (s)')
[auto_initial_guess, lags] = xcorr(noise_initial_guess);
auto_final = xcorr(noise_final);
subplot(2,3,6); plot(lags/Fs, [auto_initial_guess, auto_final]); axis tight
xlabel('time (s)')
grid on; title('linear autocorrelation')

The above script produced the following graphs (note: for those plots that have blue and red, the blue is what randn initially produced, and the red is the final random Gaussian white noise):

I'm not able to help with your first question as I don't have enough understanding of your application. The second question I've answered based on aspects I consider when performing empirical system identification to determine a system's frequency response function.
